# Can all users access the tables created in my schema?

Tags: java, sql, oracle12c

I've installed Oracle 12c, SQL Developer, and have created several tables...but in my schema.
I want to create a Oracle DB backend to a JAVA front end application.

Once created, are all schemas available to any user with the appropriate permissions or are they local to the user who created them?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your questions...  You create the database objects (tables, stored procedures, etc.) in the database, I'm not sure beyond that what "where" you're referring to.  And, of course, anyone with the appropriate privileges (for some definition of appropriate) and technical means of access will be able to do whatever those privileges allow them to do.  But that's a tautological statement so I'm not sure what you're really trying to ask.

Comment: My tables and stored procedures are in, what I understand is, MY schema.  Meaning, when I login to the database, with my user name and password, they are visible and I can add, delete, create as I wish.  So if I create a front-end GUI that connects to this database, for other users to use, will they be able to use the information that was created under my username?  I'm probably missing something fundamentally basic, but it's really tripping me up.

Comment: I'm still not seeing an answerable question.  Yes, if there is an Oracle user `corporateWhore` that owns a number of tables then there is a `corporateWhore` schema in the database.  If you have the credentials (and the `corporateWhore` account has permissions), you can log in to the database and modify the tables.  If some other user logs in to the database, that user will have whatever privileges you (or your DBA) grants them on those tables.  But we're still in the realm of tautology-- if you have privileges to do something and means to do something, you can do something.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  All tables created in a database, no matter by whom, are accessible by whomever has the appropriate permissions to access them.  I guess I wasn't sure if the tables I create under one user are local to that one user.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's more than one question. But, you create an account (or multiple accounts) to own the tables and stored procedures and functions. And yes, once created anyone can access it (as long as they have the required permissions). And yes, they can run the stored procedures and functions you create (again, if they have the required permissions).

Comment: So one schema can allow for unlimited users?

Comment: **Where** did I say that?  All software has limits.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is what is the typical application/database architecture?  How is a backend database normally structured?  One schema for many users or many schemas for many users...I'm very confused.

Comment: There is no *typical* application/database architecture (or if there is, it's so general as to be impractical). Yes. It's complicated. And there may even be multiple databases with multiple schemas and multiple users...